# Change Anypic Assets

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, parse-platform

When changing the assets in the Parse Anypic tutorial it doesn't show up in the actual simulator. The files I changed are in the `Resources` folder: `Default.png, Default@2x.png, Default-568h@2x.png, Default-667h@2x.png, Default-736h@2x.png`

For more clarification this is a picture of the files I changed.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/cjml6hs2aur9z96/Screenshot%202015-04-21%2017.09.13.png?dl=0

**Question:** How can I change the black "Home" screen - not the LaunchImage but the actual interaction. I want to re-skin the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't getting the assets changed maybe run it on an actual phone. Check to see if the assets show up or not based on your result choose between starting over and importing all your code or retrieve the assets from another project and import it to your old project

Answer (score 1):

For clarity, I'm referring to the first screen you see after logging into Facebook. This screen has three tabs at the bottom, "Home", "Camera", and "Activity". The "Home" view is controlled by PAPHomeViewController.m, and the "Activity" view is controlled by PAPActivityFeedViewController.m.

In both of these controller classes, the main background is covered by a table view and there is also a blankTimelineView that can be shown as the table view header.

To update the background, you can have a couple of options. Option 1 is to change the view behind the table view and make the table view transparent. Option 2 is to change the background on the table view itself.

In both cases, you may also want to make the blankTimelineView background transparent so the background always shows through.

If you go with Option 1, the following code can be placed at the bottom of the viewDidLoad method in PAPHomeViewController.m and in PAPActivityFeedViewController.m

```
// For simple change, set background color
// To show an image, add an UIImageView as a subview

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

// Make sure background shows through

self.blankTimelineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.tableView.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

If you go with Option 2, you can use the following code at the bottom of the viewDidLoad method in PAPHomeViewController.m and in PAPActivityFeedViewController.m

```
// For simple change, set background color
// To show an image, set backgroundView to a UIImageView

self.tableView.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

// Make sure background shows through

self.blankTimelineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: How would I change this part https://www.dropbox.com/s/rm05wp91xe6ohrf/Screenshot%202015-04-21%2019.16.42.png?dl=0 and the tab bar icons. I deleted the assets folder and the project didn't change at all. Im kind of confused

Comment: Those are completely new questions that take more than a simple answer. I can tell you that the top part is the Navigation Bar (self.navigationController.navigationBar), and you can start looking for code examples on changing the navigation bar in an iOS application. The tab bar icons are controlled by the Icon... png files in the Assets folder. I can't explain why deleting the assets folder did not change it anything - it should have caused the tab bar icons to disappear. Please accept the original answer if it was satisfactory.   Thanks.